# Django RestFramework method filter with multiple lookups

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have two models defined like this:

```
class House(models.Model):
    # all the fields here

    def capacity(self):
        capacity = 0
        for room in self.rooms.all():
            capacity += room.capacity
        return capacity

class Room(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(
        House, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='rooms'
    )
    capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1
    )
```

What i need is to filter the houses by its capacity using all number lookups(lt, lte, gt, gte, range, exact) in restframework, i did this:

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters

def capacity_filter(qs, name, value):
    # filter implementation here

class HouseFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    capacity = filters.NumberFilter(
        method=capacity_filter
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ('capacity',)

class HouseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_class = HouseFilter
    # other attrs here
```

And it works but only for exact value, i cant filter using __gt, or __lt, i tried with the *lookup_expr* parametter in NumberFilter but not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section for that at drf_filters: https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#allowing-any-lookup-type-on-a-field

Comment: I tried too, but with method argument does not work, it raise this exception:
    'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: capacity

Answer (score 0):

You could use a partial to generate a callable with the appropriate lookups. eg,

```py
def capacity_filter(qs, name, value, lookup_expr):
    # implementation

class HouseFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    capacity = filters.NumberFilter(
        name='capacity',
        method=partial(capacity_filter, lookup_expr='exact'))
    capacity__lt = filters.NumberFilter(
        name='capacity',
        method=partial(capacity_filter, lookup_expr='lt'))
    ...
```

---

That said, you should probably use an annotation to calculate room capacity, as it will perform the calculation in the database instead of in memory. This would also allow you to forgo use of the `method` argument here.

```py
# the query you want to construct
queryset = House.objects \
    .annotate(capacity=Sum('rooms__capacity'))
    .filter(...)

# filterset
class HouseFilter(FilterSet):
    capacity = filters.NumberFilter(
        name='capacity', lookup_expr='exact', 
        label='Capacity is equal to')
    capacity__lt = filters.NumberFilter(
        name='capacity', lookup_expr='lt', 
        label='Capacity is less than')

    @property
    def qs(self):
        # Only annotate capacity if filtering by capacity
        if not hasattr(self, '_qs') and self.form.is_valid() \
           and any(f.startswith('capacity') for f in self.form.cleaned_data):
            self.queryset = self.queryset \
                .annotate(capacity=Sum('rooms__capacity'))

        return super(HouseFilter, self).qs
```